# Given set of numbers, find what is x

Tags: combinatorics

hi can anybody help how to solve this

30, 32, 36 , X , 60, 92

what is X

Comment: You are probably *intended* to say $44$, because then differences go $2,4,8,16,32$.  However, from a *mathematical* point of view, the $X$ is not determined by the given data.

Answer (score 2):

The differences seem to be in G.P., i.e. the differences are $2,4,\cdots,32$ So, it must be that $X-36=8, \ 60-X=16$. $X=44$ satisfies both of them.

Answer (score 0):

I imagine that it is a strictly increasing sequence of positive integers yielding an alternating sequence $(0,2,0,2,0,\ldots)$ modulo $3$,  $(0,0,0,\ldots )$ modulo $2$,
and $(0,2,1,0,0,2,1,0,\ldots )$ modulo $5$. Hence we must have $X=50$.